# Does Flanking grant advantage on melee spell attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, advantage-and-disadvantage, flanking

### When using the optional rule, Flanking, do melee spell attacks gain advantage?

Flanking is an optional rule we utilize in our game.

> When a creature and at least one of its allies are adjacent to an
>   enemy and on opposite sides or corners of the enemy's space, they
>   flank that enemy, and each of them has advantage on melee attack rolls
>   against that enemy.

Would melee spell attacks also gain this benefit when using them while flanking an enemy? My thoughts are that it would.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, Melee Spell Attacks benefit from the Optional Flanking Rules.

Why? That's because flanking grants advantage on Melee Attacks....and a Melee Spell Attack is a Melee Attack. Just as Ranged Spell Attacks are Ranged Attacks.

IF the rules singled out Melee **Weapon** Attacks, then this would not work.

Comment: Those were my exact thoughts as well.